# No such file or directory - getcwd

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sass, sinatra, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded my Sinatra app to Beanstalk. When I go to my site my logs are returned

```
No such file or directory - getcwd
```

The app was working before. I believe the issue has to do with the fact that I added SASS to my app, but I'm not positive. In my `config.ru`, I have the following code dealing with SASS...

```
# use scss for stylesheets
Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
use Sass::Plugin::Rack
```

If it could be another issue, let me know and I can provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh. I solved it. Wasted 100 points for a problem I solved on my own. Looked like I had the wrong db gem installed in bundler.

Comment: It is preferred that you provide an answer rather than editing the question to contain the solution.  Otherwise it looks like your question is still unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out pg was installed instead of mysql2 in bundler.

Answer (score 87):

Some people received this error after trying to run from an already deleted directory.

I received this error after switching databases and leaving the server running.  The old server info was still showing up but I was getting this error.  Restarted my rails server and everything works fine with the new db.

Basically it means that there is a significant state change on the server, and your environment needs to be reset/restarted.

Comment: I was repeatedly receiving an error that contained "No such file or directory - getcwd" using VS Code on Mac.  I hit this solution from a Google search.  The last line in this comment prompted me to restart VS Code.  Turns out, it was the solution to my issue.

Answer (score 9):

The key for me was starting a new terminal session.

I just ran into this after trying `vagrant up` on a newly created directory (after deleting one by the same name) in the same terminal session (oddly, for the first time after working with Vagrant for years). In my case I had already run `vagrant destroy`, so nothing about the environment needed to or could be be restarted. I was blocked until I started a new terminal session, then `vagrant up` ran smoothly again.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this issue with an Amazon EC2 and rails 5. I had to delete my directory and git clone it. I used bundle install and rake db:migrate and afterwards I ran into the same error. All I had to do to fix it was run `sudo service nginx restart` to restart the server and when I went back to the website it was working again.