# AWS ElasticBeanstalk + Ruby on Rails: Bundler `shared_helpers` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to update my Ruby version of my Rails app and having a Bundler issue on deployment to AWS ElasticBeanstalk.

Upgrading Ruby from version `2.3.4` to `2.5.7`

- Ruby: 2.3.4 -> 2.5.7
- Rails: 5.1.7
- Bundler: 1.17.3
- Puma: 3.12.1

My ElasticBeanstalk Environment is running Ruby-2.5.7 and I am able to successfully deploy the application.

In my logs I am encountering an error when attempting to load the website.

```
=== puma startup: 2019-10-22 20:41:56 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2019-10-22 20:41:56 +0000 ===
[22501] - Worker 0 (pid: 22504) booted, phase: 0
[22501] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `getwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `block in pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:70:in `pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:272:in `search_up'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:155:in `print_major_deprecations!'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:23:in `ensure in start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:23:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I resolve this issue with my ElasticBeanstalk environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No such file or directory - getcwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505878/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd)